# Calling a super class constructor when inheriting from Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance, constructor

I'm curious why I can't call `super(Thread, self).__init__()` instead of `Thread.__init__(self)` when my class inherits from Thread.  Can you help me to understand the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
class ThreadManager(object):

    def work(self, items):
        q = Queue()
        for item in items:
            q.put(item)

        print q.qsize()

        p = Worker()
        p.start()
        p.join()

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        # Why doesn't this work?
        #super(Thread, self).__init__()

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'thread running'

def main():
    items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    tm = ThreadManager()
    tm.work(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious why I can't call `super(Thread, self).__init__()` instead of `Thread.__init__(self)` when my class inherits from `Thread`.

Because that's not how [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) works. You have to pass your *own* type as the first parameter, so it can search for the next ancestor of that type. If you pass it `Thread`, you're asking for an ancestor of `Thread`.

If your parent class is a regular new-style Python class, doing this wrong usually means you skip over one ancestor class, which may be harmless, or may *seem* to work but not actually do the right thing. But `threading.Thread` has specific checks to make sure it gets initialized properly, so you're probably getting something like this:

```
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() was not called
```

If your parent class is a C extension class, it probably doesn't have any ancestors, and it probably doesn't implement `super` even if it does, so you'll usually get an error that way too.

You may want to read [Python's super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) if you want to understand how all of this works (because the docs linked above aren't necessarily the best introductory discussion).

So, in summary:

```
super(Worker, self).__init__()
```

Comment: All the examples I was using used letters for the class names and so I got confused!  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @DavidM.Coe: That's a good point… it should remind the rest of us to stop writing examples where A inherits from B or vice-versa and come up with actual names…